# Authentication integration issue between wicket-auth-roles and spring-security-cas-client

Tags: java, spring-security, wicket-1.5

I have an issue on one of my Wicket projects.
The version of wicket I use is the 1.5.7 release, with wicket-auth-roles (same version).

I'm trying to get a CAS server integration; for that, I'm trying to use the spring-security-cas-client (3.0.7.RELEASE) but the CAS authentication isn't working at all. On this project, I am already using spring-security-core (3.1.0.RELEASE), spring-security-config, & spring-security-ldap and that works fine.

The issue I'm getting is when I first access a Wicket page. Usually I must have a CAS interrogation; but despite that, the method "getSignInPageClass" (wicket-auth-roles) of my custom  authenticatedWebApplication is called and I'm automatically forwarded to my login page (and I'm not getting any CAS call at all).

Has someone already met this type of issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same issue. To get it working, I let Wicket do the redirection to CAS and then the CasAuthenticationFilter validate the token and handle authentication. I dont know if it is the best solution, but I used a RequestMapper to handle the AuthenticatedWebSession sign-in.

Spring Security Configuration

```
<!-- https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring-security-and-wicket-auth-roles.html -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" />

    <custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER"/>
</http>
```

Override restartResponseAtSignInPage in your AuthenticatedApplication

```
/**
 * Stores original Url and redirects to CAS login for authentication. CAS will redirect back to this
 * service using the service parameter. 
 */
@Override
public void restartResponseAtSignInPage() {
    Session.get().setAttribute("originalUrl", RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getOriginalUrl());
    // This will be the URL back to the Spring CAS filter
    String service = "service=https%3A%2F%2F" + casServiceHost + "%2Fapp%2Flogin";
    throw new RedirectToUrlException("https://" + casServerHost + "/cas/login?" + service);
}
```

Make a IRequestMapper to handle the AuthenticatedWebSession sign in and redirection.

```
@Override
public IRequestHandler mapRequest(Request request) {
    logger.info("CasAuthMapper mapping {}", request.getUrl());
    // The authentication will have been handled by Spring's CasAuthenticationFilter
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    // ... Do whatever you need to do here. I added a simple method to my web session to delegate to signIn(boolean).
```